# What is the probability density function of **the multiplication of Gaussian variables**?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, gaussian-integral

Assuming $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$ are $n$ independent variables from standard Gaussian distribution $N(0,1)$. Then we construct a new variable by $y=\Pi_{i=1}^n x_i$. Can anyone show the probability density function of $y$?

Comment: See if anything [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161757/what-is-the-distribution-of-a-random-variable-that-is-the-product-of-the-two-nor) is helpful to you.

Comment: go to the logarithm, then convoluate the probability densities. $p(x_i = x) = a_i e^{- b_i (x-\mu_i)^2}$, $p(\ln x_i = t) = e^{\displaystyle- b_i (e^t-\mu_i)^2}$, $\ln y = \sum \ln x_i$, $\ln p(\ln y = t) = \ast \ln p(\ln y)\ast \ldots  p(\ln x_n)$

Comment: The problem with the logarithm approach is that the $x_i$ can be negative.

Comment: Well, to solve the problem of negative numbers in the $\log$, you could take the absolute values and take the PDF for that.  Then recognize by symmetry teh probability of the product being negative is 1/2.