# Infinite product of random matrices

Tags: matrices, random-variables, determinant, infinite-product, random-matrices

Given a $2 \times 2$ matrix

$$A(k) = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1}(k) & a_{1,2}(k)\\
  a_{2,1}(k) & a_{2,2}(k)   
 \end{pmatrix}$$

where $a_{m,n}(k) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,\sigma^{2})$ are Gaussian distributed random variables, and the product:

$$P(N) = \prod_{k=1}^N A(k)$$

If we have

$$d := \lim_{N\to\infty} \det\left( P(N) \right)$$

is it possible to prove that $d \lt \infty$?

Comment: Are you stuck at some step?

Comment: @user3658307: I only did some simulation with large $N$ $(N=10^4)$ and in some case the result is finite

Comment: In some cases it was infinite? All the $a_{i,j}(k)$ are independent right?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: The determinant can only become infinite if you have at least one infinite value in $P$, so your question boils down if the entries in $P$ are bounded.

Comment: @user3658307: yes they are independent

Comment: @MrYouMath: can you prove your statement?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: What do you mean be prove? The Determinant of P is given by $p_{11}p_{22}-p_{12}p_{21}$. It is clear that if only one of these values does diverge, then the determinant of $P$ will diverge. In the case in which many values of $P$ diverge, it will be more complicated. So, if only one entry diverges that this is sufficient for the determinant to diverge. If all entries are bounded, then this is sufficient for a finite determinant. Also, note that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.

Comment: @MrYouMath: OK. This could be a proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define the following: $$ d_N = \det\left(\prod_{k=1}^N A(k)\right) = \prod_{k=1}^N \det(A(k))=\prod_{k=1}^N a_{11}(k)a_{22}(k)-a_{21}(k)a_{12}(k) $$ where $a_{ij}(k)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.
So then the expected value is given by: $$ \mathbb{E}[d_N]=0=:\mu_N $$
Next, define $$ \hat{S}_1(k) = \hat{a}_{11}(k)\hat{a}_{22}(k),\;\;\hat{S}_2(k) = \hat{a}_{21}(k)\hat{a}_{21}(k) $$
where $\hat{a}_{ij}(k)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
So, the variance is written: 
\begin{align} 
\mathbb{V}[d_N] &= \mathbb{E}[d_N^2]= \mathbb{E}\left[ \prod_{k=1}^N (a_{11}(k)a_{22}(k)-a_{21}(k)a_{12}(k))^2 \right]\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^N \mathbb{E}\left[ (a_{11}(k)a_{22}(k)-a_{21}(k)a_{12}(k))^2 \right]\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^N \mathbb{E}\left[ (\sigma^2\hat{S}_1(k)-\sigma^2\hat{S}_1(k))^2 \right]\\ &= \sigma^{4N}\prod_{k=1}^N \mathbb{E}\left[ (\hat{S}_1(k)-\hat{S}_1(k))^2 \right]
\end{align}
Now for some random variable algebra. First, note that the $\hat{S}_i$ are [chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) because they are a product of independent normal RVs (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161757/what-is-the-distribution-of-a-random-variable-that-is-the-product-of-the-two-nor?noredirect=1&lq=1)): $$ \hat{S}_1(k), \hat{S}_2(k)\sim\chi^2_1 $$
Next, define $\mathfrak{D}_k= \hat{S}_1(k) - \hat{S}_2(k)$. The difference between two chi-squared variables (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/distribution-of-difference-of-chi-squared-variables), or [*A note on gamma difference distributions* by
Bernhard Klar](http://www.math.kit.edu/stoch/~klar/seite/veroeffentlichungen/media/note-vg-revision.pdf)) follow a [variance-gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution) (generalized Laplace) distribution:
$$ \mathfrak{D}_k\sim\Gamma_\mathcal{V}(\mu,\alpha,\beta,\lambda,\gamma)=\Gamma_\mathcal{V}\left(0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) $$
This also tells us that:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\mathfrak{D}_k] &= \mu + \frac{2\beta\lambda}{\gamma^2} = 0 \\ 
\mathbb{V}[\mathfrak{D}_k] &= \frac{2\lambda}{\gamma^2}\left( 1 + \frac{2\beta^2}{\gamma^2} \right) = 4
\end{align}
So now we can complete the computation:
$$
\mathbb{V}[d_N]=\sigma^{4N}\prod_{k=1}^N \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathfrak{D}_k^2 \right]
= \sigma^{4N}\prod_{k=1}^N (\mathbb{V}[\mathfrak{D}_k] + \mathbb{E}[\mathfrak{D}_k]^2) = 4^N\sigma^{4N} =: \varsigma^2_N
$$ 
Hopefully I didn't make any arithmetic mistakes.
Anyway, woah, so that is potentially a very large variance. Clearly it depends heavily on the value of $\sigma$. But anyway, ignoring the limit, we can bound our target using the [Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality):
$$
P(|d_N-\mu_N|\geq \varsigma_N\kappa) \leq \frac{1}{\kappa^2}\;\;\;\implies\;\;\;
P(|d_N|\geq 2^N\sigma^{2N}\kappa) \leq \frac{1}{\kappa^2}$$
Maybe there is a better [concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality).

But, if we denote $\sigma = \hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{2} $, then at least what this tells us is that: if $\hat{\sigma}<1$, then the probability that $d_N$ is non-zero is essentially zero.