# Characteristic function of random variable $Z=XY$ where X and Y are independent non-standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

I would like to find Characteristic function of random variable $Z=XY$ where X and Y are independent normal random variables, but they are *not standard*, i.e.  $$X\sim N(\mu _x,\sigma_x)$$ $$Y\sim N(\mu _y,\sigma_y)$$
where $\mu _x\neq 0,  \sigma _x\neq 1, \mu _y\neq 0,\sigma _y\neq 1$

For the standard case you can find the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74013/characteristic-function-of-product-of-normal-random-variables) , but I could not find any solution for the non-standard one. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Maple:

$${{\rm e}^{{\dfrac {t \left( -t{\mu_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}-t{
\mu_{{y}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}+2\,i\mu_{{x}}\mu_{{y}} \right) }{2({t}^
{2}{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}+1)}}}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {{t}^{2}
{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}+1}}}
$$

EDIT: As requested, here is Maple code for the characteristic function
and the PDF:

```
with(Statistics):
X:= RandomVariable(Normal(mu[x],sigma[x]));
Y:= RandomVariable(Normal(mu[y],sigma[y]));
C:= simplify(CharacteristicFunction(X*Y,t)) assuming real;
f:= simplify(PDF(X*Y,z)) assuming real;
```

It doesn't return a closed form for the PDF.  I don't know if there is one.

Comment: Actually my main problem is how to find PDF of XY. I tried different methods but I could not find it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @May: pdfs and cfs are related through inversion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas

Comment: @Alex Thanks, but I don't know how to find the following integral: $$f(u)=1/2\pi  \int_{-\infty }^{\infty}  {{\rm e}^{{\dfrac {t \left( -t{\mu_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}-t{
\mu_{{y}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}+2\,i\mu_{{x}}\mu_{{y}} \right) }{2({t}^
{2}{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}+1)}}}}{\frac {e^{-itu}}{\sqrt {{t}^{2}
{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}+1}}}
\;dt$$

Comment: @Robert Israel: I am new to MAPLE, would you please give me your MAPLE code? Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Thank you so much.