# How to find the following definite integral

Tags: integration

I would appreciate if you could help me to find the following integral:

$$f(u)= \int_{-\infty }^{\infty}  {{\rm e}^{{\dfrac {t \left( -t{\mu_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}-t{
\mu_{{y}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}+2\,i\mu_{{x}}\mu_{{y}} \right) }{2({t}^
{2}{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}+1)}}}}{\frac {e^{-itu}}{\sqrt {{t}^{2}
{\sigma_{{x}}}^{2}{\sigma_{{y}}}^{2}+1}}}
\;dt$$

Comment: This question looks like somebody *very* troubled's worst nightmare come true, but if you post such a question without giving somebackground ,explanation, showing some effort orself work I greatly doubt many will give it a serious thought...

Comment: @DonAntonio you are right! It's been a few days now that I've got stuck in finding this integral! Actually my question is how to find the PDF of product of two normal random variables. Knowing its characteristic function (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496465/characteristic-function-of-random-variable-z-xy-where-x-and-y-are-independent) ,I want to find its PDF.

Comment: and PDF is the fourier transform of the characteristic function.

Answer (score 0):

The integral could be evaluated in closed form if one could evaluate
$$\int_0^{\infty}\cos(a u)e^{-bu/\sqrt{u^2+1}}du$$. This is doubtful.

Comment: Thanks, would you please tell me how these two integrals are related?